# Angular 6: can't send HTTP POST-request from second dialog

Tags: angular, http, service, dialog, material-ui

I have trouble with sending HTTP request from dialog window in angular 6.

Firstly about situation: I click button and opens first dialog, in this dialog I click button and open the second dialog. In second dialog I fill some input data and click button Send. But when I click button Send I have next [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVr6F.png).

And I don't know what I do wrong, because from examples of sending HTTP calls all looks fine.

As you see the problem is in function sendOffer() in the second dialog (clicking button Send in dialog) when calling function addUserOfferMapping() from useroffremappingService.

employeeinfodialog.component.ts (it's the second dialog window):

```
import {Component, Inject, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {UserOfferMapping} from "../../_models/UserOfferMapping";
import {Userrole} from "../../_models/userrole";
import {UserroleService} from "../../_services/userrole.service";
import {UseroffermappingService} from "../../_services/useroffermapping.service";
import {ProjectinfodialogComponent} from "../projectinfodialog/projectinfodialog.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'employeeinfodialog',
  templateUrl: './employeeinfodialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employeeinfodialog.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeinfodialogComponent implements OnInit {
  public userinfo;
  public userprojectmapping;
  public projects;
  public roles: Userrole[];
  public offer: UserOfferMapping = {
    fromdate: null,
    chance: null,
    percent: null,
    roleId: null,
    userId: null,
    projectId: null
  };
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private userroleService: UserroleService, private useroffremappingService: UseroffermappingService, private dialogRef:MatDialogRef<ProjectinfodialogComponent>) { }

  async getRoles(){
    this.roles = await this.userroleService.getAllRoles().toPromise();
    console.log(this.roles);
  }

  public sendOffer(){
    console.log("fgfg");
    console.log(this.offer);
    this.useroffremappingService.addUserOfferMapping(this.offer).subscribe(value => {
      console.log("dfd");
      this.dialogRef.close();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userinfo = this.data.userinfo;
    this.userprojectmapping = this.data.userprojectmapping;
    this.projects = this.data.projects;
    this.getRoles();
    this.offer.userId = this.userinfo.id;
    console.log(this.userinfo);
    console.log(this.userprojectmapping);
    console.log(this.projects);
  }
}
```

employeeinfodialog.component.html:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Suggest participant in another project?</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>{{this.userinfo.firstname}} {{this.userinfo.lastname}}</p>
<!--  project-->
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Project name</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="this.offer.projectId">
      <mat-option name="select-project" *ngFor="let project of this.projects" [value]="project.id" >
        {{project.kurzname}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>From date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="this.offer.fromdate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
<!--  percent-->
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Percent</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Type percent" type="number" [(ngModel)]="this.offer.percent">
  </mat-form-field>
<!--  role-->
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Role</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="this.offer.roleId">
      <mat-option
        name="select-roles"
        *ngFor="let role of this.roles"
        [value]="role.id"
        matTooltip="{{role.description}}"
        matTooltipPosition="right"
      >
        {{role.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
<!--  chance-->
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Chance</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Type chance" type="number" min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="this.offer.chance">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="sendOffer()">Send</button>
</div>
```

useroffermapping.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {UserService} from "./user.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {UserOfferMapping} from "../_models/UserOfferMapping";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UseroffermappingService {
  private addUserOfferMappingUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'api/userofferwebservices/addUserOfferMapping';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userservice: UserService) { }

  public addUserOfferMapping(offer: UserOfferMapping) : Observable<any> {
      const data = {
        userId: offer.userId,
        projectId: offer.projectId,
        roleId: offer.roleId,
        fromdate: offer.fromdate as Date,
        percent: offer.percent,
        chance: offer.chance,
      };

      return this.http.post(this.addUserOfferMappingUrl, data, this.userservice.getRequestOptions());
  }
}
```

UPD:

error.interceptor.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {UserService} from "../_services/user.service";


@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private loginService: UserService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.loginService.logout();
                location.reload(true);
            }
            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;

            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is coming from the *error.interceptor.ts*, where is that code?

Comment: the only logical explanation is that the `err.error` object is undefined

Comment: thanks @r-richards for help! I found error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help from @r-richards and @mazbeye ! I found the error, the problem is that interceptor inccorectly catch errors and I don't see that URL configured incorrectly for this HTTP request! 
error.interceptor.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {UserService} from "../_services/user.service";


@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private loginService: UserService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.loginService.logout();
                location.reload(true);
            }
/* Change to this and see in console error about bad configured URL
            let error;
            console.log(err);
            if (err.error) {
              error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
            } else {
              error = err.statusText;
            }
*/
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```